# How center image position with fixed height

Tags: html, css

I can't show an image well with fixed height because shows stretched, i want to position image.

I want to can use large images with 300px of fixed height but the image can't show stretched.

The image link have to come in img tag because it come from database.

I put here a example code:

```css
.image
{
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.image img
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-isrPay4twtQ/UWudn23k1sI/AAAAAAAAAZQ/vDeXHzTJxeU/s1600/imagens-lindas+(1).jpeg"/>
</div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `object-fit` to get the same

> The object-fit property defines how an element responds to the height
>   and width of its content box. It's intended for images, videos and
>   other embeddable media formats in conjunction with the object-position
>   property. Used by itself, object-fit lets us crop an inline image by
>   giving us fine-grained control over how it squishes and stretches
>   inside its box.

object-fit can be set with one of these five values:

1. fill: this is the default value which stretches the image to fit the
   content box, regardless of its aspect-ratio.
2. contain: increases or decreases the size of the image to fill the
   box whilst preserving its aspect-ratio.
3. cover: the image will fill the height and width of its box, once
   again maintaining its aspect ratio but often cropping the image in
   the process. none: image will ignore the height and width of the
   parent and retain its original size.
4. scale-down: the image will compare the difference between none and
   contain in order to find the smallest concrete object size.

**[Object-fit](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/)**

```css
.image
{
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.image img
{
  width: 100%;
  object-fit:cover;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-isrPay4twtQ/UWudn23k1sI/AAAAAAAAAZQ/vDeXHzTJxeU/s1600/imagens-lindas+(1).jpeg"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `background-image` inline and just cover it using `background-size: cover;`

```css
.image
{
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
      background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="image" style="background-image: url('http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-isrPay4twtQ/UWudn23k1sI/AAAAAAAAAZQ/vDeXHzTJxeU/s1600/imagens-lindas+(1).jpeg'); "></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```css
.image
{
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
background-image:url('http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-isrPay4twtQ/UWudn23k1sI/AAAAAAAAAZQ/vDeXHzTJxeU/s1600/imagens-lindas+(1).jpeg');
background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use width and height for an image tag it will stretch the image. So use either width or height.

```
.image
{
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.image img
{
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

Or Use

```
object-fit:cover;
```

But image will crop.