# How to match bootstrap carousel to div height?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a gallery and using bootstrap's carousel, on the back end, the user can replace the images with his own - the question is what is the best way to force the image to match the parent div's size and maintains responsive? so if the user will upload an image with different sizes - it won't mess up the structure.

Here is my carousel :

```
                <div class="col-md-8 right_silder">
                <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" 
                 data-ride="carousel">
                <!-- Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-
                    to="0" class="active"></li>
                  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-
                  to="1"></li>
                  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-
                 to="2"></li>
                </ol>

                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                  <div class="item active">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/450x350" alt="Slide 1">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                      Caption Slide 1
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/450x350" alt="Slide 2">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                      Caption Slide 2
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/450x350" alt="Slide 3">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                      Caption Slide 3
                    </div>
                  </div>        
                </div>

                <!-- Controls -->
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-
                  generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-
                  hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-
                   generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-
                  hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is my [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/kSFGiBMfjoHKeoxGo2jD?p=preview)

Comment: check this ans https://stackoverflow.com/a/44541450/2724173

Comment: Thanks - i all i needed to do what add height....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add height to your parent element of carousel.
Like

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script src="script.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
 <div class="page_container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center fiche_header">
                    <p>Header 1</p>
                    <a class="en_savior_btn  selection_btn"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Shop</span></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row contact_row">
                <div class="col-md-4 left_contact">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab amet dolore esse eum eveniet iure modi, nostrum officiis porro quisquam recusandae rerum sequi tempore? Animi fugit harum impedit. Consequuntur, laborum?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 right_silder"><!-- Slider -->
                    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <!-- Indicators -->
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    </ol>
                  
                    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" style="height:300px;">
                      <div class="item active">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/450x350" alt="Slide 1">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                          Caption Slide 1
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/450x350" alt="Slide 2">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                          Caption Slide 2
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="item">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/450x350" alt="Slide 3">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                          Caption Slide 3
                        </div>
                      </div>        
                    </div>
                  
                    <!-- Controls -->
                    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks - how can i set the height to be in percent ..rather than pixels? it's not so good with other resolutions...

Comment: you can use height property in % or vh (viewport height).
eg:   height:40%;  (it will take height according your page body height)
   or height: 40vh; (it will take height according your device height)